# i need to put different background for my homepage of my weebly site

Tags: html, background, background-image, weebly

I'm making a Weebly site and want to make a different background just for the home page.  My theme does not support numerous themes, any ideas how weI can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp). you can make each page with different backgrounds..Refer the link for some interesting examples.

```
<html>
<body background="bgimage.jpg">
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Try this css code

```
<style type="text/css">
body { background-image:url(images/bg_fullpagehome.gif) }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Weebly doesn't give me the option of making each picture separately- is there any way I can do it in the css?

Comment: thanks! but where does this indicate that it is the home background?

Answer (score 0):

What I know is you can only add one background on the body area. But if you refer to your homepage, there's more than one area you can configure or customize its background.

The only trick is to find which selectors to be edited. It is also recommended to add the full url of the image when using it as a background.

Try to add the following on your homepage header code box:

```
<style>
#header {
background: red !important;
}
#topnav {
background: blue !important;
}
#nav-wrap {
background: yellowgreen !important;
}
#logo-wrap {
background: cyan !important;
}
#main-wrap {
background: green !important;
}
#main-wrap .container {
background: grey !important;
}
#main-wrap .inner-container {
background: silver !important;
}
#main {
background: orange !important;
}
#content {
background: indigo !important;
}
#header-wrap {
background: violet !important;
}
#footer-wrap {
background: yellow !important;
}
#footer {
background: black !important;
}
.blog-sidebar {
background: white !important;
}
.blog-body {
background: purple !important;
}
#banner-wrap {
background: brown !important;
}
</style>
```

And look for the changes. It might not be the best answer but this is a good start.
You may visit [Advance way of Editing Weebly Background](http://www.myweeblytricks.com/2014/08/weebly-tricks-69-advance-way-of-editing.html) for more details.

You may also use a full page background image slideshow to show different backgrounds.